# iOS 7 MapKit Crash: EXC_BAD_ACCESS in [VKRasterOverlayTileSource invalidateRect:level:]

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, ios7, exc-bad-access

I have an unreproducible crash on iOS 7 only. I'm making heavy use of MKOverlayRenderer to draw shapes on the map. This crash does not happen on iOS 6.

Any ideas of what this might be related to will be useful.

```
Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS 

Code: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x291707628

Stack:

0    libobjc.A.dylib     objc_msgSend + 5
1    VectorKit   __50-[VKRasterOverlayTileSource invalidateRect:level:]_block_invoke_2 + 38
2    VectorKit   -[VKTileKeyMap enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:] + 58
3    VectorKit   -[VKTilePool enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:] + 76
4    VectorKit   __50-[VKRasterOverlayTileSource invalidateRect:level:]_block_invoke + 178
5 ...    libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
6    libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_client_callout + 22
7    libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 268
8    CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
9    CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 1300
10   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
11   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
12   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 138
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the same problem with my MapView

Comment: I have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 5):

I found my problem. Might be that it solves yours too... In dealloc, remove all of the MapViews overlays and the crash should be fixed...

Comment: Nice. Well, my map view never gets deallocated so this won't work for me.